# Is there a web-ready text to speech engine that will pronounce phrases inputted as phonetic spelling?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I'm looking for a JavaScript library or some other web solution that will output sound based on a phonetic pronunciation that I provide.

I have looked at [Speak.js](https://github.com/mattytemple/speak-js) which sort of gets there, but rather than accept my phonetic spelling it applies its own rules on how to say the words.

What I'm looking for is basically a way to verbalize athlete names. The athletes are from all over the world, so in some cases the same spelling can result in two different pronunciations.

For example:

If I have the name  `Steven Andrade`, I have a phonetic spelling of `ON-draw-day`, Speak.js can mostly handle this, though I don't think the accent is right, but something such as:

`Juan Acevedo` => `OSS-uh-vay-doe` gets mangled as `O-S-S-uh-vay-doe`.

Comment: So text to phonetic text? Not actual audio.

Comment: No I have the phonetic text and then want to produce the audio.  For example, I have the name Lajoie.  One pronunciation is Lazh-way and another is La-joy. I want to input the particular phonetic spelling and output the audio.  Phonetic spelling in audio out.

Comment: maybe the issue is with your phonetic text? phonetics should really all sound the same, so I don't think replacing Speak.js would accomplish anything better.

Comment: What is looks like to me is that Speak.js wants to speak words rather than phonetics.  For example it outputs 'Oss' as 'O-S-S' rather than 'oss'